# Prolog - tracing a rule

Tags: prolog

Considering the following rules:

```
example(A, [A|As], As).
example(A, [B|Bs], [B|Cs]) :- what(A, Bs, Cs).
```

and the query:

```
example(c, [a, b, c, a], X).
```

results:

```
X = [ a, b, a ]
```

Can anyone help me trace how it does this? I am unsure what example it goes into first and I'm sure I can figure it out from there.

Comment: Instead, use the query `example(E, [A,B,C], Xs).` and look at *all* the answers. Tracing is not very effective in the presence of unification. And `s/what/example/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suppose, that `what` is an alias of `example` and your rules really look like that:

```
example(A, [A|As], As).
example(A, [B|Bs], [B|Cs]) :- example(A, Bs, Cs).
```

Then, things are going like that:

```
?- example(c, [a, b, c, a], X).
```

Now we look for a matching clause:

```
example(c, [a, b, c, a], X) = example(A, [A|As], As).
```

This one is **false**. So we try next one:

```
example(c, [a, b, c, a], X) = example(A, [B|Bs], [B|Cs]).
```

This one works and we get results:

```
X = [a|Cs],
A = c,
B = a,
Bs = [b, c, a].
```

So we get:

```
example(c, [a, b, c, a], [a|Cs]) = example(c, [a|[b, c, a]], [a|Cs]).
```

From the second rule of `example/3` we know that:

```
example(c, [a|[b, c, a]], [a|Cs]) :- example(c, [b, c, a], Cs).
```

So we do the process again and we get:

```
example(c, [b, c, a], Cs) = example(A, [B|Bs], [B|Cs]).
```

Which results in:

```
Cs = [b|Cs],
A = c,
B = b,
Bs = [c, a]
```

Which means that:

```
example(c, [b, c, a], [b|Cs]) = example(c, [b|[c, a]], [b|Cs]).
```

And again from the second rule:

```
example(c, [b|[c, a]], [b|Cs]) :- example(c, [c, a], Cs).
```

So we search for another match - this time first rule:

```
example(c, [c, a], Cs) = example(A, [A|As], As).
```

Now we have:

```
Cs = As,
As = [a],
A = c.
```

And now we can go back and transfer values of Cs. This is what we have now:

```
Cs = As = [a],
```

We move this to the previous results:

```
OldCs = [b|Cs] = [b,a]
```

And to the previous results:

```
X = [a|OldCs] = [a,b,a].
```